# Wait for a file using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this situation where I have to check if a file exists on the server using JQuery. I can use Jquery Ajax to do this, but I need a listener which listens on the server for the presence of the file, and if it is there, then trigger some action. 
To provide more sense here is an example,

```
client--> checks on server for file(time 0)--> not present
client--> checks on server for file(time 5)--> not present
client--> checks on server for file(time 10)--> file present--> return some message to client.
```

So How do I implement a listener which checks for some particular file on the server and notifies the user when it is available.

Comment: Okay, but what is your question?

Comment: I updated the question, sorry about that. I want to know how to implement the listener.

Comment: Can't see any reason for listener. Just check the file when you get request from the client.

Comment: If the file is not present then I need to keep checking it till it is available. How do I do that?

Comment: using setTimeout('checkForFile()', intervalInMilliseconds);

Comment: setTimeout executes a function with the interval but it doesn't execute it in a loop right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ajax polling..means check the server at a particular interval of time .

You can use setInterval function in java script to call a particular function ..And write ajax request in that function .and if the file found , just clear the timer

Check the sample code

```
var timerForLoadingResult=  setInterval(checkServerForFile,4000);//call the fnction in every 4 seconds.write ajax in that function.

function checkServerForFile() {                
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: url,                   
                success: function (result) {                        
              if(check result)  //if the file is on server 
              {
                 //do something
                 clearInterval(timerForLoadingResult)        // clear timer         
              }                 
                 ; }                 
            });

        }
```

Comment: Yeah this kind of looks like what I want. Will try it out ! thanks !

Comment: +1, great use of setInterval/clearInterval functions.  Although I think some of the nay-sayers might be horrified of a repetitive server call, with all network traffic it can generate.  I say to them -- relax, if the file doesn't exist, it is mere bytes being transferred.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to run different functions depending on the HTTP Status Code returned by the server was added in jQuery 1.5. So if the server responds with a 200 execute the function needed if file exists and if it returns a 404 execute the function required if it does not.

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      // file not found
    },
    200: function() {
      // file found
    }
  }
});
```

For more info see: [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in the jQuery docs.

Edit: From your comments I can see that you need to keep checking until the file exists. If so just wrap the request in a function and then call that function if the file is not found. Use setTimeOut though else you will be spamming the server with connection requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would start a listener thread on request and pass in a state object that listener would update after detecting the file. Also on the UI thread i would check the status of the state object if it was updated by the listener thread and perform necessary actions. 
UI thread is basically a jQuery ajax call on a timer.